# Return selected cell address in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, find, range

```
    Rows("1:1").Select
Set rng1 = Selection.Find(What:="FinalFSU", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
Selection.Find(What:="FinalFSU", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

    Range("rng1" & LR).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,'RETURNED'!A:T,20,0)"
```

Above is an example of a code Im trying to implement in my spreadsheet.

What I need:

I have columns A,B,C,D etc. I need to find each of the columns and get the address or range of first cell. Columns are usually sorted in different way, so it might be B,C,A,D and so on. I can find the header name, I can select the whole column but how to get the cell address so I can use it in my VLOOKUP?

Last string actually shows where I need to use the actual range value.

I would appreciate any help with this, because I spent whole day trying different ways to solve that problem and it didn't worked. Thank you!

Comment: I think you can't do this with a `VLOOKUP`.  `VLOOKUP` requires that your key value column always be the one farthest left in your range.

Comment: Thats right. My goal is to find the right column in the spreadsheet and populate the vlookup. the problem is that I only know the name of the column but not the actual address (like C2). If my columns were constant, my vlookup would look something like that - Range(B2 & LR).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,'RETURNED'!A:T,20,0)"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your code 'rng1' is a Range comprising a single cell, therefore your last line could become:

```
rng1.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,'RETURNED'!A:T,20,0)"
```

I would probably also replace your third line of code with `rng1.Activate`

To get the cell row/col details you have a few options:

You could use rng1.Row and rng1.Column to get the location in numbers.

Instead of using the `Range` syntax, which requires a letter and a number, perhaps you could use the `Cells` syntax which just requires numbers.  So the location of rng1 could be described as:

```
Cells(rng1.Row, rng1,Column)
```

Alternatively, if you really wanted to stick with the letter/number description, you could use the `Address` property.  So `rng1.Address` would return a value $C$1 or similar depending on its actual location.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would benefit from a number of changes.

There is no need, and it is inefficient, to use Select and/or Activate except in very particular circumstances, none of which exist in your code snippet.  Better code to Set rng1 to the cell in Row 1 containing **FinalFSU** would be:

```
Dim rng1 As Range
 With Rows(1).Cells
    Set rng1 = .Find(what:="FinalFSU", after:=.Item(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
 End With

 'optional test for non-existence of FinalFSU
 If rng1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Could not find FinalFSU"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

There is likewise no need to Select the Entire column before inserting a new column.

In your last line of code, you have placed the variable **rng1** within quotation marks.  This then becomes the string rng1 which is a cell address (Row 1, Column 12539).  I doubt this is what you really want.  Lookup the syntax of the Range object.

You never define LR.  I presume it is the last row in the same column as rng1.  Another way of obtaining the range that goes from rng1 to the last row in that same column would be:

```
Range(rng1, Cells(Rows.Count, rng1.Column).End(xlUp))
```

Try out these suggestions and then post back if you continue to have problems.